# PhoneGap: Layouts displaying not properly

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova

I'm developing app based on PhoneGap for Android devices. My app is working fine in AVD device (320x480), however in AVD with 720x1280 resolution (Galaxy Nexus) it displays layout's elements not properly, i.e. they are too small. Here is the [**LINK**](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/72519118/001.png) to screenshots. How can I fit the layout to the whatever device display?

AVD characteristics:

- Eclipse Juno IDE
- Java SE 7
- Android SDK API 17
- PhoneGap 2.7.0
- jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.3.0

and here is the **meta** tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

I'm really stuck and need to help. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain the results that you want to see and maybe I can give you a better answer.

You are dealing with different resolutions and pixel densities, so any elements that are of a fixed width and/or height are going to look differently.  In the case of those buttons, the height is fixed but the width is something like 95% of the page, so they stretch out to fill the width but are narrower because it is a fixed number of pixels high and the pixel density increased.

You will likely need to use CSS media queries to adjust the font size, widths, and heights according to the screen size and pixel density.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want to adjust the font size, widths and heights of the elements here according the display size (pixel density). In other words when I'm opening the page via screen size 720x1280 I want to see appropriate sized fonts instead of very small fonts and elemetns (listbox, buttons, etc.) that are pushed to the top of display and half of the another display (bottom side) is empty